# How to save value from a pop up to a grid

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a requirement in which I have to save values from a pop to a grid table i.e to a cell id.How can i achieve it using Jquery is there any other alternative?
Can someone post the answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

```
> <div id="yourPopup"> 
> <span class="someClass">Your value</span> 
> </div>
> $('#yourPopup').find('.someClass').text();
```

Comment: It gets the text from the popup. Then, you can do whatever you need, in your case, setting it to a cell. Check my answer to see a way to do this second part.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you can use it, but, everytime I need to use grids, I use [jqgrids](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).
The plugin has methods to do that very simply.
Of course, if you don't need all the other plugin functions, it may be 'too much'.

Comment: am using jqgrid only but does jqgrids have any functionality like this?

Comment: It surely does. If you just need to set the content of a cell, there is a 'setCell' method. But there are many others that may help in your specific case. Check out the documentation: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods